# Can you set the currentTime of audio in milliseconds instead of seconds? -Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making something that requires audio to be set at an exact time. For this, I need to use `currentTime` in javascript or an equivalent (if any exist) to set the time in milliseconds.

This is my current code, which will set the audio to start 10 seconds in:

```html
<audio id="sound" src="audio/example.mp3" preload loop></audio>
```

```
var snd = document.getElementById("sound");
snd.currentTime = 10;
snd.play();
```

I need something that would be able to set the time in millseconds instead of seconds if it is possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need millisecond precision, or are you just trying to convert Seconds to Milliseconds?

Comment: I need millisecond precision, for example: ```snd.currentTime = 10ms;``` if that was possible.

Comment: You have no information on how the "10" or "10 ms" is fetched  I am not sure if it is in reference to a slider etc, but if you want to cast from an int (seconds) to int (milliseconds) you can just multiple by 1000.  As 1 second == 1000 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var snd = document.getElementById("sound");
snd.currentTime = 0.001;
snd.play();
```

This will set the current time to 1/1000th of a second. However, the actually precision depends on the browser implementation and the device. So, you should use milliseconds to set your time, but you cannot guarantee it'll actually set the time to that precise index.